# How to Search items in alphabetically in Listview through Base Adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I want to search items from list view alphabetically on click on edittext I am not getting how to do this

```
serch_item.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override


                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     text = serch_item.getText().toString();
                    //  approvedfriendList.setFilterText(text);
                }
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

search_item is editext and items are coming through base adapter if user types name on edittext only that item should visible or searched

Comment: What I can get is you want to implement search functionality in ListView. Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16539415/2345913). I couldn't get the alphabetical part...  :(

Comment: list view is bounded with data source you can search in that data source

Comment: getFilter().filter(cs);   method not coming in base adapter it's working on array adapter in need in base adapter

Comment: so if user types "A" in edit text you want your list to display only data that is having "A" am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Take one EditText & in onTextChangeListner filter listview ...

```
private class ModelFilter extends Filter
        {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                System.out.println("In performFiltering()");
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
                {
                    ArrayList<Model> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Model>();

                    for(int i = 0, l = allModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
                    {
                        Model m = allModelItemsArray.get(i);
                        if(m.getWebsite().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filteredItems.add(m);
                    }
                    result.count = filteredItems.size();
                    result.values = filteredItems;
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(this)
                    {
                        result.values = allModelItemsArray;
                        result.count = allModelItemsArray.size();
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                filteredModelItemsArray = (ArrayList<Model>)results.values;
                System.out.println("In publishResults()");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clear();
                for(int i = 0, l = filteredModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
                    add(filteredModelItemsArray.get(i));
                //notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
       }
```

Your TexchangeListner

```
@Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                BookmarkManagerActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }



            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }



            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


            }


        });
```

Comment: i am not getting this can u send complet code or link my code is :-approvedList = new ApprovedList();
      approvedfriendList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);     
        approvedfriendList.setAdapter(approvedList);
                   i am taking adapter with name and images are in arraylist and i have to search name array list.